# Getting error when calling a method inside observable which returns another observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am new to angular and observable. I have tried flatMap, swithMap and concatMap, but nothing helps.  I have got the error " **You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable**." When the code of switch case 1 runs of inputprocessing method,while the default case works completely fine.

**app.component.ts**

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnChanges {
  ProcessInput(input: string, session: string): void {
    this.appService
      .ProcessInput(input, session)//this works fine and returns the response.
      .pipe(
        concatMap((res: any) => {
          return this.inputProcessing.inputProcessing(res);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.arr.push("TEST");
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }
  }
```

**inputprocessing.service.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Container, inject, injectable, AsyncContainerModule } from "inversify";
import { OutputResponse } from "../response";
import { PrescriptionStatus } from "src/Classes/PrescriptionStatus";
import { service } from "./service.service";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { CourierMode } from "../enums/CourierMode";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, flatMap, concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { PrescriptionStatusMain } from "src/models/PrescriptionStatusResponse";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class InputprocessingService {
  constructor(private service: service,private http: HttpClient) {}

  responseText: string;
  returnMessage: string;
  inputProcessing(response: OutputResponse): Observable<any> {

    this.responseText = response.output.generic[0].text;
    //works completely fine with default case, but when case 1: runs it gave an error
    switch (this.responseText) {
      case "1": {

        const obsFail = new Observable(observer => {
          observer.next(this.returnMessage);
          observer.error();
          observer.complete();
        });

        this.service.getStatus().pipe(
          concatMap((res: StatusMain) => {
            return obsFail ;
          })
        );
        break;
      }

      default: {
        const obs = new Observable(observer => {
          observer.next(this.responseText);
          observer.complete();
        });
        return obs;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import * as request from "request";
import * as request_promise from "request-promise-native";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { StatusMain } from "src/models/StatusResponse";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class service {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getStatus(): Observable<StatusMain> {
    const body = { bdate: "1999/05/01" };
    return this.http.post<StatusMain>(
      "http://localhost:49995/api/Status",
      body
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputProcessing` function in your service needs to return an observable. With your implementation the created observable only emits the value, while the `concatMap` expects an observable. Hence the error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Try this:

```js
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnChanges {
  ProcessInput(input: string, session: string): void {
    this.appService
      .ProcessInput(input, session)//this works fine and returns the response.
      .pipe(
        flatMap((res: any) => {
          return this.inputProcessing.inputProcessing(res);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.arr.push("TEST");
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
   }
  }
```

And in your service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class InputprocessingService {
  constructor(private service: service,private http: HttpClient) {}

  responseText: string;
  returnMessage: string;
  inputProcessing(response: OutputResponse): Observable<any> {

    this.responseText = response.output.generic[0].text;
    let returnObservable;

    //works completely fine with default case, but when case 1: runs it gave an error
    switch (this.responseText) {
      case "1": {

        const obsFail = new Observable(observer => {
          observer.next(this.returnMessage);
          observer.error();
          observer.complete();
        });

        returnObservable = this.service.getStatus().pipe(
          concatMap((res: StatusMain) => {
            return obsFail ;
          })
        );
        break;
      }

      default: {
        returnObservable = new Observable(observer => {
          observer.next(this.responseText);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }
    }

    return returnObservable;
  }
}
```

Note how `AppComponent` implements `flatMap`. `flatmap` must return an observable. Hence `inputProcessing` creates a local variable (`returnObservable`) which holds a reference to different observables (switch statement: case1, case2... default).

When the inner observables emit value, then `returnObservable` emits that value to the outer `flatMap`.

Comment: Got the same error. Debugger goes to the getStatus() method of the service.ts class, but as it is the http call so it will return observables. At that time the switch case ends as it did not wait for the http call to finish.

Comment: It shouldn't wait for it to finish. Since the http call returns an observable, that observable will be assigned to `returnObservable`. Then `returnObservable` is returned to the `flatMap` operator.

Answer (score 0):

**inputprocessing.service.ts**
This code resolved the issue.

```
@Injectable({
      providedIn: "root"
    })
    export class InputprocessingService {
      constructor(private service: service,private http: HttpClient) {}

      responseText: string;
      returnMessage: string;
      inputProcessing(response: OutputResponse): Observable<any> {

        this.responseText = response.output.generic[0].text;
        let returnObservable;

        //works completely fine with default case, but when case 1: runs it gave an error
        switch (this.responseText) {
          case "1": {      
    //This line solved the error.
            return this.service.getStatus().pipe(map(res=>{return res}));
            break;
          }

          default: {
            returnObservable = new Observable(observer => {
              observer.next(this.responseText);
              observer.complete();
            });
          }
        }

        return returnObservable;
      }
    }
```